# Has anyone managed to get HotSpot 2.0 access point (Passpoint) information (ANQP) by Android code?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

A few devices are able to connect to HotSpot 2.0 access points, also named "Passpoint". In my application, I can connect by code to Wi-Fi access points, including EAP, and I'd like to be able to connect to Passpoints as well, and I need to have access to ANQP information. There is no official Android API to get the ANQP information sent by HotSpot 2.0 access points. Has anyone managed to find a way of handling HS2.0 access points by code, other than generating a whole Android system using [wpa_supplicant_8](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/wpa_supplicant_8/+/master/wpa_supplicant/README-HS20) (I need to keep "standard" Android)?
Thanks,
Coralie

Comment: Hi, did you get to know how to do that?